# Efficient way to find median value of a number of RGB images

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, median

I'm playing around with a script in Python where I want to find the median of a number of images of same dimensions. That is, I wan't to take all (red, green and blue) pixels in position [x,y], and construct a new image with their median values.

My current method uses Python PIL (the imaging library), but it is quite slow! I would very much like to use the OpenCV (cv2) interface, since it loads every image directly as a numpy array. However, I keep getting indices wrong when stacking x images of dimension (2560,1920,3). Any help?

My current, inefficient code with PIL, is the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops,ImageDraw,ImageFilter,cv
import sys,glob,sys,math,shutil,time,os, errno,numpy,string
from os import *

inputs = ()
path = str(os.getcwd())
BGdummyy=0
os.chdir(path)
for files in glob.glob("*.png"):
    inputs = inputs + (str(str(files)),)
BGdummy=0
for file in inputs:
    BGdummy=BGdummy+1
    im = cv.LoadImage(file)
    cv.CvtColor( im, im, cv.CV_BGR2RGB )
    img = Image.fromstring("RGB", cv.GetSize(im), im.tostring())
    vars()["file"+str(BGdummy)] = img.load()
imgnew = Image.new("RGB", (2560,1920))
pixnew = imgnew.load()
for x in range(2560):
    for y in range(1920):
        R=[];G=[];B=[];
        for z in range(len(inputs)):
            R.append(vars()["file"+str(z+1)][x,y][0])
            G.append(vars()["file"+str(z+1)][x,y][1])
            B.append(vars()["file"+str(z+1)][x,y][2])
        R = sorted(R)
        G = sorted(G)
        B = sorted(B)
        mid = int(len(inputs)/2.)
        Rnew = R[mid]
        Gnew = G[mid]
        Bnew = B[mid]
        pixnew[x,y] = (Rnew,Gnew,Bnew)
    BGdummyy = BGdummyy+1
imgnew.save("NewBG.png")
```

Comment: I've never used it but it might be worth checking `scipy` - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html - which will load it as an array which you can use for manipulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will demonstrate on how to do it with 5 small arrays of size (3,3,3).

First I will create 5 arrays, then keep them in a list X. In your case you will have keep your 30 images in this list. ( I am doing it in a single line )

```
X = [a,b,c,d,e] = [np.random.randint(0,255,(3,3,3)) for i in xrange(5)]
```

Next you flatten each image to a long single row. So earlier your image would be like

```
[R1G1B1 R2G2B2 R3G3B3,
 R4G4B4 R5G5B5 R6G6B6,
 R7G7B7 R8G8B8 R9G9B9]
```

This will change into `[R1 G1 B1 R2 G2 B2 R3 G3 B3......... R9 G9 B9]` . Then you stack all these flattened images to form a big 2D array. In that array, you see, all first red pixels comes in first column and so on. Then you can simply apply np.median for that.

```
Y = np.vstack((x.ravel() for x in X))
```

I lattened each image and stacked. In my case, Y is an array of size 5x27 (row - number of images, column - number of pixels in an image)

Now I find median of this Y and reshape it to our original image shape :

```
Z = np.median(Y,axis = 0)
Z = np.uint8(Z.reshape(a.shape))
```

Done.

Just to make sure it is working fine, let's check the value of arbitrary pixel, say `Z[0,1,2]` :

```
In [50]: G1 = [x[0,1,2] for x in X]

In [51]: G1
Out[51]: [225, 65, 26, 182, 51]

In [52]: Z[0,1,2]
Out[52]: 65.0
```

Yes, the data is correct.

Comment: My issue is that I have, say, 30 images, and I want to convert their median values into a new image. So what I need is: 3 stacks with the red, green and blue pixels. x- and y-direction is the direction of the pixels, while the z direction is individual images. At each pixel, (x,y), I want the median value in the z-direction. So my biggest issue right now is to find a way to stack the images in a sensible, 3D way where I can then utilize the "np.median" command you suggested.
Please let me know if it doesn't make sense, then I'll try to elaborate =)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Check me if I am correct : You have 30 color images. Result is also a color image. In result image, first pixel's blue value is median of first pixel->blue value of all 30 images. Similarly for red and green etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly (or any number of images). I can do it do it right now with the PIL library, but it is rather slow since I need to use the "load pixel" command. I would like to keep everything in Numpy and OpenCV (2) as you already suggested. But basically I've fumbling with adding the numpy arrays in a good way to get the median values. Thanks in advance!

Comment: But isn't memory expensive? You need to load 30 images into memory.

Comment: Memory is not expensive in this context. Even 30 images in tiff format and 2560x1920 should not be a problem, only ~420 mb.